# Passing data from front-end to create a dynamic multer destination folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, multipartform-data, multer

How can i pass the `uploadYear` from the Angular Service to the Multer destination in order to have a dynamic path such as './public/uploads/' + uploadedYear?

The way multer works, seems very twisted to me and i'm incapable of figuring out where to store an extra object so it can make it all the way to the Multer Destination.

Basically i see no trails of how `myfile` travels from the front-end to the back-end or how can i access it on the back-end.

**Angular Service**

```
    this.uploadCV = function (file, uploadYear) {
        console.log(uploadYear)  //output 2017
        var fd = new FormData()
        fd.append('myfile', file.upload)
        return $http.post('/api/uploadCV', fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        })
    }
```

**API**

```
var cv = ''
var CVstorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg)$/)) {
            var err = new Error()
            err.code = 'filetype'
            return cb(err)
        } else {
            cv = file.originalname
            cb(null, cv)
        }
    }
})
var uploadCV = multer(
    {
        storage: CVstorage,
        limits: { fileSize: 10000000 } //limit 10 MB
    })
    .single('myfile')

//API Route
router.post('/uploadCV', function (req, res) {
    uploadCV(req, res, function (err) {
            if (!req.file) {
                //error handle
            } else {
                res.json({ success: true, cv: cv })
            }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send it as params in header:

```
 $http.post('/api/uploadCV', fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 
              'Content-Type': undefined,
              'path': uploadYear
            }
        });
```

Then in your backend you can get it by **req.headers.path**

Comment: I added the `path` in the services, tried putting `console.log(req.query.path)` in `router.post('/uploadCV', function (req, res) {...}` i get output undefined, also i tried putting it into `uploadCV(req, res, function (err) {...}` still undefined

Comment: do you use expressJS? could you try console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));

Comment: Yes, `console.log(req.headers.path)` worked.! Thanks I think you can change your answer to that.

Comment: awesome, glad it helped, answer is changed ;)